# GET request in a for loop

Tags: python, get, request, python-requests

I want to execute a get request inside a `for` loop.

```
url = 'http://192.168.1.5:8888/listen'
parameters = { 'string' : 'A'}
for x in range(0, 5):
    print "Get request number " + str(x)
    r = requests.get(url, params=parameters)
    time.sleep(5)
```

After the first execution of the for (my output is "Get request number 0"), the program is stuck in the loop.
How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Your loop has a set number of iterations. It's not clear what you mean by "stuck"

Comment: Does that url work in something else other than your script? ie: is the request happening, or is it waiting for the other end to either accept it, or close the connection for the get to return ?

Answer (score 0):

`/listen` suggests to me that something funky is going on. My first step to debugging this is to set a timeout, as indicated by the [official docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts): "By default, requests do not time out unless a timeout value is set explicitly. Without a timeout, your code may hang for minutes or more."

You should also specify timeout as a tuple if your connection and read timeouts should be different.

```
url = 'http://192.168.1.5:8888/listen'
parameters = { 'string' : 'A'}
for x in range(0, 5):
    print "Get request number " + str(x)
    r = requests.get(url, params=parameters,
                     timeout=(4, 27))
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Hmmm, I _strongly_ believe that requests have a default timeout. Not doubting you linked to the official docs but I could swear I have system logs of timeouts at work; I wonder if the docs are out of date?

Comment: @roganjosh see my quote from the official docs in the answer, I was surprised too

Comment: @roganjosh If you test this I would be very interested in your results

Comment: I will have a look tomorrow. This can't be correct, surely? I'll let you know.

Comment: Ah, I think I might be thinking about a no-response. A _failed_ connection will time out, but not when waiting for a server response?

Comment: I think you're right in the sense that a failed connection condition would not be the same as a timeout condition and instead `r`'s status code would end up being something from the 4 or 500 block. That's my guess anyway @roganjosh -- if you logged the status code you can check it out in depth

Comment: There's definitely a timeout and a max number of retries by default, but if the server gives some obvious error, it can time out. I have a feeling that a timeout is an explicit exception that you can even catch. Very curious. Atm I'm on my phone so it's laborious to try research. For sure I'm following this up tomorrow.

Comment: @roganjosh please do very interested

Comment: Thanks all of you. The output with the timeout is "requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.5', port=8888): Read timed out. (read timeout=27)"

Comment: Yep @user3836982 that explains it. Nothing wrong with your code the problem resides at the endpoint. if this response helped resolve your issue please mark it as answered

Comment: @roganjosh he said the output with the timeout parameter -- he was hanging when he should have been timing out